# Reference problem for indian tourist visa from Bangladesh

Tags: visas, india, bangladesh

Hi everyone just filling in our visa application forms to visit **india** from the **Bangladesh** and they are asking for references in India and the Bangladesh.I don't know anyone in India.Can anyone suggest me how could i fix it out?

Answer (score 1):

For the reference name in India you can put down the name of a hotel in the area where you are going.   You don't necessarily have to book a room. The Visa website than asks for the address and the phone number. Keep this information on hand upon arrival in India because you will probably be required to supply it.